# MFC Unclickable Button (Running away from cursor on MouseMove)

Tags: c++, mfc

How would i make a button that will change it's position on MouseMove Event if the cursor is close enough to the center of the button in MFC ?

Comment: What are you going to do when the user pushes the button against a window border or corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WM_MOUSEMOVE is not delivered to the button if the cursor is not over it (and is not captured, but you don't want that). So you have to process WM_MOUSEMOVE in the parent dialog. If you want your button to be a self-contained control, you have to subclass the parent window upon button creation.

Subclassing, in this context, means:
 - you retrieve and store the parent's window proc address with GetParent()->GetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)
 - you set it to your procedure with SetWindowLong()
 - in the procedure, you call the parent's previous window proc, after handling WM_MOUSEMOVE the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

The WM_MOUSEMOVE coordinates will be relative to the screen, but you'll probably want to track the button position relative to the window that contains it. Use the ScreenToClient method on the parent window to convert, then you can compare the coordinates to see if it's close. Then use MoveWindow to move the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you track the mouse cursor position you can determine when the cursor gets close to or enters the button window rect. You can then use the [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to reposition the button window in the parent window client area.